# Cannot read property 'get' of undefined and $http is not a function - Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm quite new to Angular and I'm having issues with injecting `$http` into the following controller:

```
function(){
    angular.module('nps-settings-support-tools', [])
        .controller('SettingsSupportToolsController', [ '$scope', 'Settings', 'gettextCatalog', '$q', '$timeout',
            '$rootScope', 'SweetAlert', 'CurrentUser', '$http',
            function($scope, Settings, gettextCatalog, $q, UploadFile, $timeout, $rootScope, SweetAlert, CurrentUser, $http) {
                var apiUrl = '/api/v1/';
```

I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29061460/http-post-undefined-is-not-a-function) that Angular cares greatly about the order of injections, but I've double-checked that the ordering is correct. Yet, when I'm running:

```
$scope.doTodo = function() {
    return $http.get(apiUrl + 'support?tool=digest&type=todo');
};
```

I get the following errors in the console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at Scope.$scope.doDetractors
```

So, thinking that my memory was incorrect, I also tried with:

```
return $http({url: apiUrl + 'support?tool=digest&type=responses', method: 'GET'});
```

Which obviously fails also because `$http` appears to be undefined, yet I can't see where I've gone wrong, as most SO questions / answers are about ordering of injections and accessing `$http` via an improperly ordered injection, which I'm not doing (as far as I can see).

Does anyone know what is going on, please?

Comment: please check again there are 9 modules are injected and you have 10 arguments in function, so you are doing same mistake other doing :p

Comment: Yep, I see that now, thank you :) What a dolt!

Comment: Double checking is not enough, triple check it!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have parameter UploadFile in the controller function, but not in the array of strings.